# Collect python output in Swift

Tags: python, swift, macos, cocoa

is it possible to store the output of a .py file in a swift variable?
In my xcode project I have put a python script.
I run this script using this code

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    var pathForFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "eject", ofType: "py")
    let path = "/usr/bin/python/"
        
    override func viewDidLoad() {
            
            let arguments = [pathForFile]
            let task = Process.launchedProcess(launchPath: path, arguments: arguments as! [String])
            task.waitUntilExit()
            super.viewDidLoad()

        }
}
```

If I put  `print(x)` in the python file, once executed I can see the x value on the output window of xcode.
I also tried to put `return x` in the main function and then tried to set `let y = task.waitUntilExit()` in the swift file, but the only thing I get is an empty variable

I don't know much about swift, so please forgive my lack of knowledge. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Should there be a trailing `/` on this line? `let path = "/usr/bin/python/"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift: How to read standard output in a child process without waiting for process to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33820746/swift-how-to-read-standard-output-in-a-child-process-without-waiting-for-proces)

Comment: @Willeke Not really, but it helped me out. Now I'll post the answer i found, thanks by the way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

As explained in this page 
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-run-an-external-program-using-process
and shown in the answer suggested by Willeke, you can use `Pipe()` to do that.

I changed the code as shown below.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let task = Process()
    task.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/usr/bin/python")
    let filename = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "eject", ofType: "py")
    task.arguments = [filename!]
    let outputPipe = Pipe()
    task.standardOutput = outputPipe
    
       do{
           try task.run()
       } catch {
           print("error")
       }
    
    let outputData = outputPipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let output = String(decoding: outputData, as: UTF8.self)
    print(output)
    
   }
```

Be sure to put this

```
let outputPipe = Pipe()
task.standardOutput = outputPipe
```

before the `task.run()` command and this

```
let outputData = outputPipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
let output = String(decoding: outputData, as: UTF8.self)
print(output)
```

after it.