# NSTask process hangs reading from my pipe

Tags: swift, macos

I'm trying to use `NSTask` (or `Process` since this is Swift) to execute `xmllint` to format some XML data. The problem is that the task seems to hang.

I'm using `xmllint` rather than `XMLDocument.xmlData(withOptions:)` because the output better matches what I need. I'm writing a tool to edit existing files and I want to minimize the impact.

I tried killing the `xmllint` process while it was hung, and got the first 84 1/2 lines of the output. The output should be about 10,000 lines for that test case, and most of the content involves elements nested only a couple of levels so it's not a very complex task.

Am I setting up the process and pipes correctly? The documentation is vague and I had a hard time finding directly applicable examples.

The code:

```
  public static func format(xml: XMLDocument) -> Data?
  {
    let data = xml.xmlData
    let task = Process()
    let inPipe = Pipe()
    let outPipe = Pipe()


    task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/xmllint"
    task.arguments = ["--format", "-"]
    task.standardInput = inPipe
    task.standardOutput = outPipe
    task.launch()
    inPipe.fileHandleForWriting.write(data)
    inPipe.fileHandleForWriting.closeFile()
    task.waitUntilExit()  // Hangs :(
    return outPipe.fileHandleForReading.availableData
  }
```

Comment: It could be the same issue as in [cURL through NSTask not terminating if a pipe is present](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36009175/curl-through-nstask-not-terminating-if-a-pipe-is-present) – try reading *before* waiting for process exit.

Comment: That did it! Thanks!