# How to redirect stdout to NSScrollView in Swift 4.0 Cocoa Application?

Tags: cocoa, swift4

I have a simple NSButton function executing a 'ls -la' command:

```
@IBAction func Convert(_ sender: NSButton) {
    let path = "/bin/ls"
    let arguments = ["-la"]
    sender.isEnabled = false
    let task = Process.launchedProcess(launchPath: path, arguments: arguments)
    task.waitUntilExit()
    sender.isEnabled = true
}
```

I need the stdout in my NSScrollView:

```
@IBOutlet weak var Output: NSScrollView!
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Real time NSTask output to NSTextView with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29548811/real-time-nstask-output-to-nstextview-with-swift)

Comment: To set the _text_, you need a `@IBOutlet` of a `NSTextView` that's supposed to be inside the scroll view. If you just added a scroll view in your interface file, you should replace that with a NSTextView (which is automatically wrapped in a scroll view). You can then use `textView.string = "..."` to replace the text with the result of the output (see answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `Pipe` and a `FileHandle`

```
let path = "/bin/ls"
let arguments = ["-la"]
// sender.isEnabled = false
let task = Process()
task.launchPath = path
task.arguments = arguments
let outputPipe = Pipe()
task.standardOutput = outputPipe
task.launch()
task.waitUntilExit()
let data = (task.standardOutput as! Pipe).fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
let output = String(data:data, encoding: .utf8)!
print(output)
// sender.isEnabled = true
```

And please conform to the naming convention that variable and function / method names start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Could you please explain how to link print(output) to my NSScrollView?

Comment: A scroll view cannot display text directly. It's a container for another view.

Comment: If a scroll view is not able to display the output what else can I use to display the output in my app?

Comment: An `NSTextView`. It's one of the views a scroll view can contain.

Comment: Output.documentView!.insertText(output)