# How to show real time result while using terminal command in a swift script

Tags: swift, xcode

I am using [Xcode Project Renamer](https://github.com/appculture/xcode-project-renamer) to rename my Xcode project, after that I used the code below to install pod file.

It's working good but the terminal showing result after pod installed. I want to show result while installing the pod.

```
@discardableResult
private func shell(_ command: String) -> String {
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = "/bin/bash"
    task.arguments = ["-c", command]

    let pipe = Pipe()
    task.standardOutput = pipe
    task.launch()
 //   pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()

    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let output: String = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String
    return output
}


    let command = shell("pod install")
    print(command)
```

Can someone help please.

[image]

Comment: What result, I don't see any intermediate result in that code?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/38088651/1187415z