# How can I show output of a command in real time using Swift?

Tags: swift, bash, macos

All the solutions I've found so far don't work with find command like [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29548811/real-time-nstask-output-to-nstextview-with-swift). For some reason the output doesn't get flushed immediately with even line separators '\n'.

Example for command: `find ~/ ! -path '/Users/username//Library/*' -type f -size +2G`

I just want to get real-time output from that command, the output can be seen in terminal in real-time but from all methods like mentioned above I've tried it waits till end of execution then flushes all output.

Comment: So the one who downvoted the question, at the very least he/she should mention the reason...

Comment: I got a workaround by appending -exec echo {} \\; which flushes from pipe buffer the file path but of course it's far from a perfect solution.